# One Day Description View for SharePoint 2010 Calendar

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, web-parts

I am attempting to create a Menu web part that will display just the description of a daily calendar event within the entire web part. Each day there would be a different menu, so ideally each day there will be a new description being displayed within the web part. This seems like a simple request, but I haven't been able to find any resources online that allow this. Basically I just want to show just the description of the calendar event for the day. Is this at all possible?

-SB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would be required to create a dataviewwebpart and you have to tweeks its xslt so that it filters out the results for the day
you can refer the following post to learn basics of dataview weparts
http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2009/12/sharepoint-list-web-service.html